# Python. Получение уникальных значений из словаря, в котором "значение" является списком

Tags: python, python-3.x

Добрый день.
Есть словарь:

```
favorite_languiges = {
'Mike': 'python',
'Jake': 'c',
'Steve': 'ruby',
'Alex': 'c#',
'Max': 'ruby',
'James': ['delphi', 'python']}
```

При попытке получить уникальный набор значений через `set()` получаю ошибку:

```
print(set(favorite_languiges.values()))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Как можно получить список уникальных значений из словаря такого вида?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Например:

```
favorite_languiges = {
    'Mike': 'python',
    'Jake': 'c',
    'Steve': 'ruby',
    'Alex': 'c#',
    'Max': 'ruby',
    'James': ['delphi', 'python']
}

langs = []
for lang in favorite_languiges.values():
    if type(lang) == list:
        langs += lang
    else:
        langs.append(lang)

print(set(langs))  # {'c#', 'python', 'c', 'ruby', 'delphi'}
```

Answer (score 3):

Как-то так:

```
In [41]: set(' '.join(x if type(x) != list else ' '.join(y for y in x) for x in favorite_languiges.values()).split())
Out[41]: {'c', 'c#', 'delphi', 'python', 'ruby'}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
langs = set()

[langs.update(set(x) if isinstance(x, (list, set)) else [x])
 for x in favorite_languiges.values()]

print(langs)
```

Вывод:

```
{'c#', 'delphi', 'c', 'ruby', 'python'}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def values(dt):
    for value in dt.values():
        if isinstance(value, list):
            yield from value
        else:
            yield value
langs = set(values(favorite_languiges))
```

--

```
langs = set()
for value in favorite_languiges.values():
    getattr(langs, 'update' if isinstance(value, list) else 'add')(value)
```

--

```
langs = set(v for value in favorite_languiges.values() for v in (
    value if isinstance(value, list) else [value]))
```